# Changing ActiveRecord attribute value in before_save hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I needed to fix the encoding of an ActiveRecord attribute and decided to do it in a before_save hook. And at this point I noticed an unexpected feature. When I wanted to change the value of the attribute, simple using the `attribute_name=XY` did not work as I expected. Instead of that I needed to use `self[:attribute_name]=XY`. So far did not recognise this behaviour and I used `AR.attribute_name=XY`. What is the reason for this? Does this behaviour relate to the hook or something else? Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is in fact a Ruby "feature":

```
def value=(x)
  p x
end

def run
  value = 123
end

run
# => 123
```

In #run above, doing value assigns a *local* variable, not anything else. If you want to call #value=, you have to specify the receiver:

```
def run
  self.value = 123
end

run
123
# => nil
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe an example with an ActiveRecord class would be better here?

Comment: @phonk64 the question is in the context of a Rails application, but the error is a pure-Ruby one. Adding the context of Rails or ActiveRecord would not add any significant new knowledge.